# When I try to build the FNF Kade Engine's source code it won't work (lime test and build wise)

Tags: haxe

```
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/eval/_std/haxe/Exception.hx:39: characters 4-53 : Array<haxe.StackItem> should be haxe.CallStack
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/eval/_std/haxe/Exception.hx:42: characters 4-48 : Array<haxe.StackItem> should be haxe.CallStack
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/eval/_std/haxe/Exception.hx:57: characters 27-44 : Class<haxe.CallStack> has no field exceptionToString
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/eval/_std/haxe/Exception.hx:82: characters 20-27 : haxe.CallStack has no field asArray
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/eval/_std/haxe/Exception.hx:4: lines 4-89 : Field stack has different type than in core type
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/eval/_std/haxe/Exception.hx:4: lines 4-89 : haxe.CallStack should be haxe.CallStack
export/release/windows/haxe/ApplicationMain.hx:298: characters 1-8 : Build failure
```

It creates the export folder but it's missing the exe.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Add in what commands you used for building, and if you wrap lines in single quotes they become more legible

Comment: also add the version of haxe being used to do the compilation in addition to @WurmD's comment